# How many moderators do we get?

Tags: discussion, election

How many moderators do get? Debating on nominating others or myself, but if we only get 2 for example I'd be happy leaving it for JohnB and Yisela.

(The tag `election` alone wasn't sufficient for posting, so including `discussion` tag as well.)

Comment: Check your inbox: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concerned, **all SE sites get 3 moderators on graduation.**

I know there have exceptions for sites needing more, so it's a matter of presenting *the case* to SE and see what they think.

I would personally like to see 4 mods, because just in the last couple of weeks the site has grown quite a lot, and it shows, but is just my opinion!

Comment: So that's three moderators in total (not three new moderators on top of the existing ones)?

Comment: @user568458 Exactly. 3 moderators voted in the elections.

Comment: This is correct. 3 new moderators, but the pro tem mods are always eligible to run in this election. If after the election as things start to smooth out and there is need for a 4th mod, we have been known to call up the runner-up when necessary (if it's within a certain amount of time since the election).

Answer (score 1):

Every election I've been a part of has had 3 people become moderators at each election. If it's desired, another election could be held sooner, the moderators would just need to make a request to SE, who would set up another election, if their work load becomes unbearable.

Comment: Related: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/978/2857 Are you sure there haven't been sites where 4 mods were elected? I remember having a conversation about this, but now I'm unsure if it's what you are referring to (another election). Will look into it.

Comment: As the SE election only allows for voting for 3 candidates, SE usually doesn't want to have more than 3 moderators elected. I can't recall seeing this violated, even SO elects only 3 per election.